# file include with if condition in php?

Tags: php, forms, include

My html is like this

```
<form name="time" method="POST" action="add.php">
    <input type="text" name="empcode" id="empcode" class="textbox" placeholder="822"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="totaltime" id="totaltime" class="textbox" value = "50" /><br />
    <strong>Start Date</strong><input type="date" name="sday"><br />
    <strong>End Date</strong><input type="date" name="eday"><br />

    <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

When user fill data in `$_POST['sday']` and `$_POST['sday']` the add.php file will include file.php otherwise file2.php

I tried this in add.php

```
if(isset($_POST['sday']) && isset($_POST['eday'])){
    include('file1.php');
}
else{
    include('file2.php');
}
```

But its not working should I check with zero value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `!empty()` instead of `isset()`.  those fields will always be set, at least to an empty string.

```
if ( !empty($_POST['sday']) && !empty($_POST['eday']) ) {
```

Comment: this will generate notices if these aren't sets.

Comment: @Loïc No... it won't.  http://php.net/empty  "empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist."

Comment: An important side note is that if "0" is a valid entry for a field, using `empty()` will not work as expected; in this case it may work, though, can't really tell what constitutes as a valid date.

Comment: @Jack Yes, there are many conditions for `empty()` to return `true`.  Fortunately for this case, '0' is probably not a valid value.

Comment: @Brad Not many conditions, actually, because posted fields are either strings or arrays :)

Answer (score 1):

`isset()` only checks whether a variable is defined and not equal to `null`. If a posted value is not filled in, it will most likely be an empty string.

Therefore, you should check for empty strings, too:

```
if (isset($_POST['sday'], $_POST['eday']) && 
        strlen($_POST['sday']) && 
        strlen($_POST['eday'])) {
```

**Why not `empty()`?**

You could use `empty()` as well, but due to `empty('0')` yielding `true` you would need an extra condition leading to more cumbersome code.

Comment: `!empty()` is sexiest than `strlen()`

Comment: @Loïc Nay, because `empty('0') == true`.